# how to use the ternary operator to compare 2 variables from 2 different tables in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, compare, laravel-blade

I used following way to use ternary operator to compare 2 variables from 2 different tables in laravel

```
@foreach ($creations as $creation)
@foreach ($usera as $user)
<div class="list-wrapper">
     <div class="col-md-4">
           <a class="btn btn-sm {{ $user->creation_id == $creation->id  ? 'btn-primary btn-removeList' : 'btn-primary btn-addList' }}"
                            data-model-id="{{$creation->id}}">
                  {{$user->creation_id == $creation->id ? 'delete' : 'add'}}
           </a>
     </div>
</div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

I cannot figure it out what is wrong with this code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`??` is a null coalescing operator. You are using it along with the other half of the ternary operator which is wrong. Ternary operator is used like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm {{ $user->creation_id == $creation->id ? 'btn-primary btn-removeList' : 'btn-primary btn-addList' }}"
                 data-model-id="{{$creation->id}}">
    {{$user->creation_id == $creation->id ? 'delete' : 'add'}}
</a>
```

Change `??` to `?` and you should be fine.

Comment: what exactly is not working. do you expect delete and its showing add?

Comment: when I press add then the button changes to the delete button, and when pressing the delete button it will change to the add button

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
<a class="btn btn-sm {{ ($user->creation_id == $creation->id)  ? 'btn-primary btn-removeList' : 'btn-primary btn-addList' }}"data-model-id="{{$creation->id}}">
     {{($user->creation_id == $creation->id) ? 'delete' : 'add'}}
</a>
```